# How to make sure my hashes are unique?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, token, unique

I am creating short 5 character hashes to make unique classrooms for my students... a typical hash will look like `AJ678`.

I am generating the hash like this:

```
public function generateToken($length = 5)
{
    return strtoupper(substr(md5(rand()), 0, $length));
}
```

I am expecting many thousands of classrooms to be generated over the lifetime of the app... so eventually there will be a clash... I want to know how to make sure that every hash will be unique.

I have make the `token` field a unique field.

I would think that the best way to do this would be to generate the hash, then check if the hash already exists in my database, if it does then generate a new hash, else use the hash.

Is that the correct way to go about this?

**EDIT: I am a bit insecure about implementing a function that calls itself... does this look right?**

```
public function generateToken($length = 5)
{
    $token = strtoupper(substr(md5(rand()), 0, $length));
    if ($this->tokenExistsAlready($token)) {
        $this->generateToken();
    } else {
        return $token;
    }
}

public function tokenExistsAlready()
{
    $this->db->where('token', $token);
    $query = $this->db->get('classes');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, when it generates a token check if it already exists in the DB, otherwise generate a new one.

Comment: I would suggest using timestamp and id ( or other primary key that you may have ) and you will probably not end up with repeated tokens or check the uniqid()

Comment: @Ian, I have updated my question with some code, not sure if you are familiar with PHP... does that look right?

Comment: It looks right but there's a slightly diffrent approach that will  save you a query: Make your token column unique. Execute your UPDATE/INSERT instruction with it, and if you receive a constraint violation error, do it again. That way you don't have to check first.

Comment: Bug:  You should pass `$length` back in on the recursive call.  Else when asking for len 6, some will come back len 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define "unique". Unique in our terms is a string of any length, that does not yet exist in your database.

This pretty much answers your question. You can never be sure, that your string is unique, unless you check it against your database. The longer the string, the slimmer the chance. So in your case, I would have created a `while` loop checking the database. Starting with the second string you save in the database, you might (and probably will later down the timeline) hit two randomly generated strings in a row. So checking the uniqueness in a loop until you find the "unique" one is a good idea. Something abstract like this:

```
$token = generateToken();

while(tokenExists($token))
{
    $token = generateToken();
}
```

Keep in mind, that **nothing** guarantees true uniqueness of a string. You may use the MySQL `UUID()` or `UUID_SHORT()`, PHP `uniqid()` or anything else, that generates a random string. But it still does not guarantee the said uniqueness unless you check it against the existing database.

Comment: Didn't think of using a while loop... thanks for the answer.

Comment: Starting with the second string you save in the database, you might (and probably will later down the timeline) hit two randomly generated strings in a row. So checking the uniqueness in a loop is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

use uniqid() function

```
public function generateToken($length = 5)
{
    return strtoupper(substr(uniqid(md5(rand()), 0, $length)));
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, this seems like a great, easy solution, I am all up for that. Need to understand how uniqueid works... I mean how can it be aware of what is already in my database?

Comment: This wont' give any guarantee that the 5-chars string doesnt exists in the database, which was the question.

Comment: @Thomas G, that is the type of thing that's going to wake me up at 3am, in a cold sweat. I am truncating the md5 hash which means the likelyhood of a clash is higher... so if uniqueid generates two unique strings `abc123ksdrfhj` and abc123lskkivm` and I truncate to the first 5 chars they both will be `abc12`, which for me will result in a clash.

Comment: To expand on my comment : uniquid generates a string based on a microtime and you won't guarrantee a sufficient uniqueness and entropy if you trunc its results to 5 chars.

Comment: Don't over complicate things. I am with Ian on this one: Generate, check if the value exists in the DB and if yes repeat. That's the best approach with a 5char string.

Comment: @ThomasG okay, I have updated my question with some code, would it be possible to give me some feedback, does that look right?

Answer (score 0):

Can the token be simply a unique integer?  That would be easy to generate with a table with a single, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, column.